# Pyorient : Create an edge in OrientDB without using raw query

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

I tried

```
graph.create_edge(Friend, orientRecord1, orientRecord2)
```

But I get AttributeError: 'OrientRecord' object has no attribute '_id'

because orientRecord does not have an _id in it. What am I doing wrong? How can I use this function?

Here are my class structures

```
class Person(Node):
    id = String(unique = True)
    name = String()
    pass


class Friend(Relationship):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an edge with the "command" statement:

[image]

and the result is this:

[image]

That is correct output, since the graph is this :

[image]

Comment: again raw query :\